# how to externalize properties from http:conduit java

Tags: java, ssl, configuration, cxf

I'm trying to externalize the "name" of an "http:conduit" because I want to configure it from an external file. My code is this, somebody knows how to do it?

```
<http:conduit name="https://myExternalPath/services/.*">

    <http:tlsClientParameters secureSocketProtocol="SSL" disableCNCheck="true">
        <sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:certStore file="${certificateName}" />
        </sec:trustManagers>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>

</http:conduit>
```

I want to externalize the name of the http:conduit as I'm doing with" sec:certStore.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4811 and vote for it!